# The action path of a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The explanation below is big, but the question is really simple.

I'm doing a simple form project in https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/full-stack-ruby-on-rails/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/forms.

The first part where I am, I need to build a form manually - so that I can see how Rails does a lot for me when I use its helper methods.
I'm stuck in this point:

**Specify the method and the action attributes in your  tag (use $ rails routes to see which HTTP method and path are being expected based on the resource you created).**

The routes.rb file looks like this:

resources :users, only: [:create, :new]

I don't know how to determine which method should I use for the form - post or get.
I don't know how to determine which action path I should use.

I've gone into the internet, Rails guides and etc, and have solved the other topics so far, but for this one I can't get through it.

My form so far:

```html
<form action='/create' method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
<label for="username"></label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
<label for="email"></label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<label for="password"></label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Once I run it in the server and then submit the form - which I did - I should get:

"Submit your form and view the server output. Oops, we don’t have the right CSRF authenticity token **(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)** to protect against cross site scripting attacks and form hijacking. If you do not get an error, you used the wrong method from step 1."

Comment: If you use a form builder rails will handle the authenticity token for you [Form Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: That's the thing. I'm doing first it manually in HTML. The part I have trouble then is not about the CSRF, but actually how to determine the action path attribute and the method attribute of the form tag. Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: You already have that part correct. `<form action='/create' method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">` Your error is the token which the post below will help solve. That being said I am not certain why you would want to "do it manually in HTML" as this is not a general practice when developing in rails and honestly would likely be frowned upon by code reviewers.

Comment: If you are just asking how can I see what routes were recreated then you open a terminal navigate to the root of your application and type `rake routes` this will show you the HTTP verb, the route name, the controller#action that handles this request

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Rails is smart) When u are sending the request to your server, Rails must know from where this request is coming. In short, if your form sending the CSRF token then Rails understand that u send this request, otherwise someone else on your behalf (CSRF attack).

To fix this bug u need to set `<%= form_authenticity_token %>` in your `.erb` view. It will generate this input that is below

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="your_token_generate_by_rails">
```

Or for your testing purposes, u can use this in your controller which is processing your request. But never use it in future if you are don't know what are u doing)

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I got that part about the CSRF. I'll insert that after I get through the part of specifying the action path attribute and the method attribute of the form. But, Idk how to determine them. Could you please help me?

Comment: @caiosa oh, if u want to determine them than run in console rake routes, there u will see your application routes

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I did so. How do I choose which one is the correct?

Comment: If you want to save something than you need to use POST method, if you want to retrieve resource than GET, for more information u should read this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi there fellow Odin student!

It looks like you're doing [this lesson.](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-on-rails-forms) Me too!

It sounds like you're asking about what value to use with `action` attribute in the form.

When I created a form using the Rails formHelper methods, I inspected the HTML that Rails created when I was previewing the app/website (`rails s`). By opening up the Developer tools (F12 key, or right click the mouse and choose inspect)I was able to see that the form Rails created had an action equal to the name of the resource, with a forward slash in front of it.

#### So for your example, the resource created is "users". So the action attribute would be `/users`

to be complete, the solution would be something like: `<form action="/users"...`

Hope this helps!